# How to serve static image in Rails 5 without using Asset Pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a web based app with the back-end build on **Rails 5.** I am using **AngularJS** for the front end. I am not using **Asset Pipeline** to serve any static content, all my **scripts(JS&CSS)** are loaded in the **index.html** file located in the `public directory` and from there I'm using angular's **ng-route** to further manage the location.

The problem arises when in one of my **HTML** page I need to include an **image** using the **HTML image tag**, the problem is that the server cannot find the image file.

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" style="padding-bottom:20px;" />
```

I tried keeping my image both in `app/assets/images` and `public/assets/images` **directory** but on all the instances I get routing error stating no route found in my rails server console.

Referring to several stack overflow answers I tried this line in my config development.rb file :

```
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

But it didn't work. So how can I have served images without using the Rails Assetpipeline?

Comment: Try giving `<img src="/assets/logo.jpg" style="padding-bottom:20px;" />` instead of  `<img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" style="padding-bottom:20px;" />`

Comment: Tried that as well, it did not worked.
http://localhost:3000/assets/images/logo.jpg

Answer (score 5):

To serve images without using the asset pipeline, put your images in the `public` directory.

An image at `your_app/public/images/logo.jpg` is referenced using `<img src="/images/logo.jpg` in your view.

Rails also provides a helper method for this, which generates the same code but provides some additional Rails features:\

```
<%= image_tag('/images/logo.jpg') %>
```

Again, you omit the `public` part of the path. Furthermore, I'd advise against having a directory in `public` called `assets` - that will get overridden by the asset pipeline. It'll also confuse you. I'd change that directory name to something else.

Comment: I did that as well, getting a routing error in rails server console.
No route matches [GET] "/images/logo.jpg"

Comment: Started GET "/images/logo.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-11 14:37:29 +0530
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/logo.jpg"):
  
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'

Comment: Okay, could you update your question with the full directory structure?

Comment: Also this is a really bad idea not to use the asset pipeline. You should be using the new webpacker gem or you're going to have a lot of trouble whenever you updated your JS and past visitors have the previous version cached.

Comment: Worked for me, but the correct url was `www.mysite.com/myimage.png` (no public/images, even though it was in the public folder inside the app)