# How to set up the asset pipeline in an ongoing project in Ruby on Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Im returning to this to build a small portfolio site for myself. I have image and code assets that Im trying to incorporate into the rails project Im walking myself through via a Rails Tutorial book and the internet. I was wondering if someone could or had any easy to understand resources or ways to set up the Asset pipe line? I cant get my images to appear on my homepage, I tried the images-url line in the corresponding homepage.css.scss file. I just feel like Im doing this wrong. Can any walk me through this?

```css
.socmed_facebook
  {
    background-image: image-url( "facebookicon.png" );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
  }
```

Edit: Ive been following the guides on how to use and set up the pipeline but my images still dont seem to show up, maybe Im missing something? OR is it better to use it with out it?

Comment: Which environment are you runnning it? Probably you should use `background-image: image-url( "assets/facebookicon.png" );` , but you have to allow serve static assets.

Comment: From what I can tell, Im in development. How do you allow static assets? I missed a bunch since the last couple of verisons, plus the tutorial I am following is having me use Cloud9 as a IDE.

Comment: Follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481824/how-to-serve-static-image-in-rails-5-without-using-asset-pipeline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve static image in Rails 5 without using Asset Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481824/how-to-serve-static-image-in-rails-5-without-using-asset-pipeline)

Comment: Im trying to use the pipeline, I've tried following the rails guide for it. And even added the gems and such for it. But nothing seems to be linking right

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020842/rails-wont-load-asset-pipeline) and it solved my problem, Thank you Alvaro!

Comment: Nice! Good job!